# org.json.simple.JSONObject not found

Tags: java, json

Thank you for your help. I am trying to convert from `JSON` to string Java object.I have checked that some libraries are needed to carry out this. I am having a problem to satisfy `org.json.simple.JSONObject`. Do you which jar solves this problem? I have added the next jars:
[image]
Thank you in advance for your help.

Cheers

Comment: what is the error provided by the eclipse? And please check which package is being used for JSONObject in your class?

Comment: Everything that @Garry mentioned in his answer.Plus in project build properties, make sure whatever the library you want is actually added to your project's build mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please dont add same jars multiple times in your classpath, try to keep one.

Try with adding only ["json-simple-1.1.jar"](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar) to your classpath.